# passing defaultBlock "pending" param to a truffle-contract call

Tags: web3js, truffle, truffle-contract

I need the pending balance of my contract.
As far as I understand I could do it with web3:

```
web3.eth.call(callObject [, defaultBlock] [, callback])
```

Can I pass defaultBlock to truffle-contract abstraction as well or I need to call web3 directly?

I.e. When I'm trying to pass a defaultBlock to a truffle-contract call:

```
import { default as Contract } from "truffle-contract";
let contractDef = Contract(artifacts);
contractDef.setProvider(provider);
let instance = await contractDef.deployed();
let balance = await myContract.instance.balanceOf(
         address,
         "pending"
     );
```

I get:

```
Error: Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function
```

Answer (score 0):

There were issues with this [before](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/596), please downgrade to truffle 3.x , delete the build/contracts/ folder (back it up just in case), rebuild the artifacts with truffle migrate --compile-all and try again.